# Making a String really immutable

Tags: java, string, mutable

I've got a question but to get an answer the following *fact* has first to be accepted: in some cases, Java Strings can be modified.

This has been demonstrated in the Artima article titled: *"hi there".equals("cheers !") == true*

Link: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=4864

It still works nicely in Java 1.6 and it surely goes somehow against the popular belief that consists in repeating *"Java Strings are always immutable"*.

So my question is simple: can String always be modified like this and are there any JVM security settings that can be turned on to prevent this?

Comment: As I understand it (but I may be mistaken on this), it's done by accessing the underlying *char[]* array using reflection and as array content cannot be made immutable in Java this hack does work.  So can something be done to prevent access to that *char[]* ?

Comment: I suppose you can always turn off the 'Hacking Java Internals' switch and everything will be just fine.

Comment: So you are attempting to prevent a [DailyWTF scenario](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Disgruntled-Bomb-Java-Edition.aspx). Well, good luck with that. I don't think the language designers can come with an idiot-proof design for such scenarios.

Comment: There is always the option to drill down in native code and start modifying random memory locations...

Comment: @pap No, there isn't. If you're accepting code from unreliable sources (and some systems have to), you should be able to isolate them in a virtual machine. And indeed it is possible.

Comment: @biziclop Well, i was half joking but the example involves running Java code in static initializers in the same running context (JVM and classloader) as the original source. Assuming we are in the same running context, you can indeed add a JNI library with some static initialization that modifies memory directly since it will exist in the same virtual address-space as the rest of the Java process.

Comment: @pap You don't have to be in the same classloader, that's the slightly scary aspect of it. Native library loading can also be restricted. It's not that easy to get out of a well-designed sandbox, you'll have to exploit a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a SecurityManager. [This site](http://aminurrashid.com/english/java/core-java/prevent-reflection-to-access-private-methods-and-members-in-java-classes.html) has an example and explanation:

Run with:

```
java -Djava.security.manager UseReflection
```

And the code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.security.Permission;

public class UseReflection {
    static{
        try {
            System.setSecurityManager(new MySecurityManager());
        } catch (SecurityException se) {
            System.out.println("SecurityManager already set!");
        }

    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Object prey = new Prey();
        try {
            Field pf = prey.getClass().getDeclaredField("privateString");
            pf.setAccessible(true);
            pf.set(prey, "Aminur test");
            System.out.println(pf.get(prey));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Caught exception " + e.toString());
        }

    }
}

class Prey {
    private String privateString = "privateValue";
}

class MySecurityManager extends SecurityManager {
     public void checkPermission(Permission perm) {
         if(perm.getName().equals("suppressAccessChecks")){
             throw new SecurityException("Can not change the permission dude.!");
         }

     }
}
```

Comment: Technically correct answer. But, I doubt using this SecurityManager in production is worth the trouble it might cause. I simply cannot come up with a list of libraries/APIs that might actually need the `ReflectPermission` with `suppressAccessChecks` at runtime, but I suspect that a few application servers would simply break, and all of this only to prevent some rogue code from running.

Comment: Having said all this, there are quite a few libraries that potentially depend on this behaviour, Wicket's PropertyModel for example.

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds Hopefully you're not designing cloud servers. :)

Comment: @biziclop, your comment might be hilarious but it is also thoughtful n a way. What if GAE had this SecurityManager? I can imagine the outcome would be a security theatre.

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds I didn't mean it personally, just a bit of a joke really sparked by the "only to prevent some rogue code from running" part of your comment. In most cases this risk is negligible, but there are some specialized areas where it is important. Anyway, what you say is interesting: why would closing the loophole in encapsulation be a security theatre?

Comment: @biziclop, well, it would be a security theatre for a cloud solution assuming the use of a single JVM for multiple apps, and that a rogue application can modify the outcome of method invocations other applications by mere reflection. If one were really serious about security on the cloud, a JVM-per-app/process-per-app solution would be a better fit.

Comment: ÁVineet Reynolds I see what you mean. But even with separate VMs you'd probably want to avoid your app server classes being tampered with.

Answer (score 5):

All reflection operations are subject to checks by the `SecurityManager` you installed.

And if you're worrying about malicious code, you must have a `SecurityManager` anyway. If not, then I wouldn't bother. If people want to shoot themselves in the foot so desperately, they should be allowed to.